# Remote Desktop Connection | Scrambles open app windows when reconnecting

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, desktop, remote

Problem: When I connect to my pc inside my office bubble via RDP on a PC that is on the other room(Trading floor) all the application windows I had previously carefully placed on either monitor 1 or 2 will be "scrambled". Either all applications show on monitor 1 and monitor 2 is empty, or they have switched 1 <-> 2.

Expected behaviour: When I connect I see all the application windows on exactly the same position and in the exact same size as I left them the night before.

I have the exact same monitors at the other room as I have in office: U2415 Dell. Same Main monitor configuration (in this case the left Monitor).

This one has been bothering me for a long long time now, I hope someone has a solution or workaround for me.

I want to use both monitors, so I have checked the "Use all monitors" setting in the RDP client. For example I leave my mail and total commander on the right monitor, and visual studio and Firefox on the left monitor. When I connect to RDP I want to see those applications on the same positions and sizes.

Comment: Try using the “/multimon” switch on the mstsc.exe command line: /multimon -- Configures the Remote Desktop Services session monitor layout to be identical to the current client-side configuration.

Comment: hi Harrymc. Thanks mate for the input. But , isn't it the same as enabling the "Use all monitors" in the RDP client?